# What the heck is Captain Styles carrying around with him?

Tags: star-trek, props, the-search-for-spock

In Star Trek III - The Search for Spock, we are presented with Excelsior's Captain Styles, a bit of a preening martinet. He is first seen greeting Mr. Scott in Engineering, and he is carrying...something. A riding crop? A SPAAAAACE RIDING CROP? What is this thing? We see it again when he is in his quarters.

[image]

What is it? Does anybody have any idea? If it's a riding crop, then for God's sake, why is he carrying it around on board a starship?

Comment: I don't know about the engineering scene, but I always thought in the picture you showed he was using a nail file.

Comment: LOL - sorry, I'm referring to the object in the upper right. Yeah, he's filing his nails with a SPAAAACE nail file.

Comment: That's why you put hand-drawn circles in your screenshots.

Comment: Maybe this one instead; http://www.startrek.com/uploads/assets/articles/swag-stick.jpg?

Comment: Wait, are you saying there are NO HORSES on Starfleet starships? Why not? Are you sure about that?

Comment: Any chance it's a sonic screwdriver?

Comment: Wrapped handle, metal knob on the end, what looks like a reddish lens... does he have a lightsaber?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to an interview with James B. Sikking (Captain Styles) on Startrek.com, we learn that it was a [swagger stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_stick), which was a military accessory common in the 19th and early 20th centuries.

> **Q. Whose idea was the swagger stick that Styles wielded?**
>
> **SIKKING:** *I think… I think… I don’t know. I’m not sure if it was mine, but it was certainly a good idea. When I was studying acting
> years and years and years and years ago, we’d have a class and they’d
> say, “Go to the bus depot or to the train station or the airport. Take
> a little bag with you. Wear dark glasses. And go sit somewhere and
> observe people.” It’s true; you sit there and watch people, and how
> they move their bodies is far more communicative than dialogue. So any
> kind of a prop that reveals a character is well worth having in your
> hand or next to you.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Startrek.com - "Hill Street Blues' Lt. Hunter Was... Star Trek III's Captain Styles"](http://www.startrek.com/article/hill-street-blues-lt-hunter-was-star-trek-iiis-captain-styles)</sup></sub>

The goal was to *visually* convey the [script direction](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/tsfs.txt) about Styles' personality

> The elevator door opens, and as Scott is preparing to step in, CAPTAIN
> STYLES steps out. Styles is an officer about Kirk's age. If he's a
> little stuffy, it's pardonable; he does, after all, have the plum
> assignment in all of Starfleet.

Comment: Wow, that interview with Sikking is terrific. I knew him from HSB before I saw him in Star Trek (even as a kid), and he was a very cultured, intelligent man who took his role in Star Trek as seriously as if he were doing, if you'll pardon the expression, Chekhov...

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens - When you hire a pro, you get a pro

Comment: I wonder who designed that prop. The thing is massive, looks more like a spanner than a swagger stick.

Comment: @ths - It looks like the gearshift from a 2230 Chevy Supernova

Answer (score 21):

I think you are close with your idea of a riding crop. From his attitude and context of military command I am pretty sure it is meant to be a [swagger stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swagger_stick).  In this case of the riding crop variation.

As a martinet this would be right in character for such an officer.

Comment: SpaaaAAACE SWAG! #yoloTrek

Comment: It also fits the acting profile of [James Sikking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Sikking) who, before being Cptn. Styles, played Lt. Hunter, another *martinet* type, on Hill Street Blues. It seems he was being typecast for the movie based on his HSB character.